# Lists not indexed, "Error in the Site Data Web Service"

Tags: 2007, search, crawl

I have a number of lists scattered throughout my site collection that have recently stopped indexing for Search, and there are errors in the crawl log for these lists of "Error in the Site Data Web Service. (The given key was not present in the dictionary.)" After the error the lists are no longer present in the index. The lists in question are in different subsites, don't have unique permissions and don't seem to have anything of note in common. The site collection does indeed have a top-level site and none of the posts on this error in any forum that I've found seem to apply here.

Running MOSS SP2 and we've had no configuration changes that I'm aware of. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to recreate your Search Service Application? Or do an Index reset?

Comment: Yes to the index reset, not yet on recreating the service. Interestingly, if I copy one of the offending lists (custom list with only 4 columns, nothing special) to another site the copy doesn't index either.

Comment: I would try to recreate your search service application. Something funny is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing this old question. The issue turned out to be that we had a third party solution (KwizCom Rating and Tagging) implemented and when our admins ported the index jobs to a new server they failed to install the KwizCom assemblies on the new server. This was the root cause of the index failures and when we installed the assemblies to the index server all was well.

Comment: Thanks for updating - do you mind if we close this as "too localized"?